# how to sort the dictionary by value ,but if the values ​are equal, it will sort by key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, sorting

I want to sort the dictionary by value, but if the values ​​are equal, it will sort by key:

example:

```
average_grades={mitra:19,sara:20,mayk:19.5,jorj:19}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
average_grades={'mitra':19,'sara':20,'mayk':19.5,'jorj':19}
```

> You could sort by:

```
from collections import namedtuple

average_grades={'mitra':19,'sara':20,'mayk':19.5,'jorj':19}

# Make the dict more specific
name_grade = namedtuple('name_grade', 'name, grade')
average_mapper = map(lambda key : name_grade(key, average_grades[key]), average_grades)

# Sort enter code here the dict by the grade then the name
sorted_dict = {key : value for key, value in sorted(average_mapper, key=lambda info: (info.grade, info.name))}
print(sorted_dict)
# {'jorj': 19, 'mitra': 19, 'mayk': 19.5, 'sara': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the dictionary from the sorted items.  Sort the items by (value,key) which is the inverted tuples produced by .items()

```
average_grades = dict(sorted(average_grades.items(),key=lambda i:i[::-1]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{i[0]:i[1] for i in sorted(average_grades.items(), key= lambda x: (x[1],x[0]))}
```

Sorted function takes a key on which it can sort, the first level is the value in ascending order, hence x[1], and the second level is key in ascending order, hence x[0]. If you had to sort on the keys in descending order, then you would write -x[0].

Comment: *"If you had to sort on the keys in descending order, then you would write -x[0]."* That wouldn't work here: `x[0]` is a string so you can't apply negation to it. (To be fair, I'm assuming the keys are strings: they're actually posted as if they were variable names, so it's not impossible that `mitra` etc are in fact numerical variables)